# Extracting information from table within invoices

Tags: machine-learning, python, object-detection, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to find specific information from supplier invoices using ML. Now, I have a lot of invoices I can use for test (+100k). I figure the first step is to label them, so I can train a model to extract the information I need.

Below is a sample invoice (I have anonymized it by removing the shipper, logo etc.).

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I am trying to extract three entities from the invoice:

1. table
2. amount (for each line in the table)
3. tariff (for each line in the table)

Now I actually don't need the table, but what seems to be common across all my supplier invoices is that the `amount` and `tariff` for line imtes, is always within a table.

My idea of a pipeline is:

- Get all invoices (PDF files) and convert each page to a PNG image.
- Label all the individual pages, using a label annotation tool, to label `table`, `amount` and `tariff` - including the **bbox** information for each label.
- Train a model using the above dataset.
- ???

My questions are:

- Does this seem like a good approach to such a problem?
- Do I have to split up the model into two? With this I mean, does it make more sense to *first* identify the `table` within an image with **one model**, then serve the table image to another model, and extract the `tariff` and `amount` with the 2nd model?